# Cannot connect to MySQL database, socket error

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, database-connection

I'm new to **php**, and while trying to make a connection on one of my pages to the database I set up on the **phpMyAdmin** page of my site.

**I get this error:**

> "Database connection failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server
>   through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (46) (2002)"

I don't know what a socket is, or why it's trying to go to what looks like a temp file, so I don't even know where to being to troubleshoot this.

The code I'm using to make the initial connection is this:

```
<?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "xxxx");
define("DB_PASS", "xxxx");
define("DB_NAME", "tester");

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

// Test if connection occurred.
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() .
        " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
}
?>
```

I know I should have access to the **MySQL** databases, since I logged on and made them myself.

I previously set the page up by using **WAMP** on my computer, and everything worked fine.

It's just when I tried making it live on the site that I ran into this error.

Any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting my hosting service several times, it seems the error occurred because my hosting service recently changed their specifications and now uses "mysql" instead of "localhost" in the host and server fields. I had used "localhost" before with another host service, so I didn't think to change this, and the latest help articles on my host's website had not updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost.`

If that does not solve it, and you have root access to your server, try the following command

```
service mysql restart
```

To restart the mysql server.

The first option will probably work. Again, if you have root access to your server, you should change the mysql config to support sockets, since it's better than the TCP-ip connection.

Comment: I tried changing it to 127.0.0.1, but now it just gives me the error:  Database connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61) (2003)      I'll look into mysql config change I guess.

Comment: That message more or less states that there is a problem with your mysql service. Are you on shared hosting or your oqn machine?

Comment: My client pays for a hosting service online